# Problems with Django logout on URLs

Tags: django, logout

I'm beginner with Django and I've resolved my problem yet, but I want to understand...

I've a login page on my app and a logout page, here is it:

urls.py:

```
url('deconnexion', views.logout, name='deconnexion'),
url('connexion', views.connexion, name='connexion'),
```

views.py:

```
def connexion(request):
    error = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ConnexionForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)  

            if user: 
                login(request, user)  
            else: 
                error = True
    else:
        form = ConnexionForm()

    return render(request, 'dashboard/connexion.html', locals())


@login_required(login_url='/dashboard/connexion/')
def logout(request):
   django_logout(request)
   return redirect(reverse(connexion))
```

If I change place for url: connexion in place of deconnexion, my script doesn't work... I don't logout me and I'm redirected on the connexion page which is being connected...

If somebody have an idea?

P.S.: Sorry for my poor English, I'm French... And French with English.... we all know it's complicated... sorry ;)

Comment: You can use [Django User Authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/), then you don't have to handle these auth operations yourself.

Comment: Please clarify: what do you mean by "change place"? in urls.py or in views.py? Ho and bienvenue to StackOverflow :)

Comment: I don't really understand what you have done, but the problem is probably in your URLs; you should either use anchors before and after the patterns (`r"^connexion$"`) or use `path()` instead of `url()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and your welcome message :)
Indeed, it's in my url, Thanks @Régis B. MD. Khairul Basar and Daniel Roseman  for your help, it was my anchors... I'm a noob XD

Comment: The problem was probably due to the fact that the `r"connexion"` regex matches the "deconnexion" string.

Answer (score 0):

As described in django [documentations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.logout) you can do like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect(reverse(connexion))
```